# what is the use of Dispatcher.BeginInvoke method in windows phone apps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I came across a code which has Dispatcher.BeginInvoke method in it , i have googled it to learn more about it but didnt find any good tutorial. Can anyone explain what is Dispatcher.BeginInvoke and in what cases i should use it...

I have read it somewhere that it is used to update UI elements, I am updating UI elements normally and never find any difficulty.

Please explain why one should use this in wp8 silverlight apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke Method (Action)` is a method that Executes the specified delegate asynchronously on the thread the Dispatcher is associated with. it takes a parameter as `System.Action` that we wanted to perform through the thread asynchronously. It Returns Value Type as `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation` An object, which is returned immediately after BeginInvoke is called, that represents the operation that has been posted to the Dispatcher queue.

e.g.

```
Control.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
        //Work to do with Thread
    //..............
    });
```

One of the most common tasks you need to perform in a Windows Phone application is `updating the UI from a separate thread`. For example, you may be download some content asynchronously using a WebClient class and when the operation is completed, you want to update the UI with the content that was downloaded. Updating the UI directly from an asynchronous thread is not allowed, as UI controls are not thread-safe.

The easiest way to update the UI from an asynchronous thread is to use the `Dispatcher` class. To determine if you can update an UI directly, you can use the `CheckAccess()` method. If this method returns a `true`, it means you can directly update the UI. Else, you have to use the `BeginInvoke()` method of the `Dispatcher` class to update the UI in a thread-safe manner.

For more Refrence you can read this article [Windows Phone Tip: Updating the UI from an Asynchronous Thread](http://weimenglee.blogspot.in/2013/07/windows-phone-tip-updating-ui-from.html)

Answer (score 1):

All UI elements should be updated only in UI thread. Each thread has it's own dispatcher. In case if you need update UI from non-UI thread, you should call _dispatcher.BeginInvoke, where _dispatcher is dispatcher object from UI thread.